# How can i check my cron job is running or fail?

Tags: unix, cron

How can i identify my cron job is processing successfully or fail in Unix.

eg

```
1 * * * * sh /usr/Script/Pri_Ip_Status.sh > /tmp/pri_log
```

Comment: Check `/var/log/cron`

Comment: Additionally, check the output in `/tmp/pri_log`, and the timestamp on that file, as well as looking for e-mail generated by `cron` when your script produces output on stderr...

Answer (score 1):

check `/tmp/pri_log` this file . if any error coming while cron job append in this file. In every min it will change.

> `/tmp/pri_log` if you are giving like this get all logs.
>   in script first check current working directory declared or not. other wise all cronjob script take home as current directory whether script in particular location also.